# Canada's Transit Visa - Do I need to send off my passport?

Tags: visas, transit, canada, indian-citizens

I have applied for a Canadian Transit Visa for my trip coming up next month (I only have 28 days left), to India from USA. I wasn't aware of this requirement, but happened to check yesterday and realized I needed one (I am an Indian citizen). I applied online, by uploading the requested documents. The processing time for a transit visa is listed to be 10 working days, typically (http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/france/visas/processing-traitement.aspx?lang=eng).

My question is, would I have to send my passport, to have the Visa entered? Or if anyone has done this before, what are my next steps, and how is the Visa delivered? If anyone can provide a comment on the processing time based on their experience, that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

[From the official website](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/guides/5256ETOC.asp#5256E4), it certainly seems you'd be submitting your passport:

> If your application is approved, any original documents, including
>   your passport if submitted with your application, will be returned to
>   you with the requested visa.

A google image search for it also shows it as a full page visa in the passport.

Processing times vary depending on your visa office, and the latest times [are available on the CIC website as well](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/times/temp/visitors.asp).