# Do I need to mail my passport when applying online for a Canadian visitor visa?

Tags: visas, canada, brazilian-citizens

I want to apply online for a visitor visa to Canada, from Brazil (I'm a Brazilian citizen).

After I submit the required digital documents and forms, do I need to send my physical passport by mail?

How long does the entire process take?

My vacation period will be in December and I want to visit Canada. I'm not sure if there is time to do everything.

Comment: [This question here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58474/canada-transit-visa-will-i-need-to-submit-my-passport-or-does-it-come-electron) could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you don't need to mail your passport right away. They first process your online application, and then request your passport only when/if you're approved-in-principle. You would then send it to  http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/offices/missions/sao-paulo.asp (or there may be visa processing centres throughout Brasil, I'm not sure).

Disclaimer: I've only dealt with Russia, the process for Brasil may be different, you should read the rules online.

As for how long it takes: I only have experience with the Moscow office, but I had a great experience with it. I've seen two applications where the visa was approved in 4 working days (that's 4 days until they sent the passport request, plus the mailing time of the passport back and forth of course), even though the official waiting time is something like 45 days. But of course, apply as early as possible.

Comment: Thank you Eugene. With the help of your answer I found out that after the online approval I must send the passport to local VSF office. In Brazil we have it on tree cities, including São Paulo.